# How can I draw a hollow rectangle using CreatePen?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

Since using the DrawArc function in GDI+ isn't very accurate when drawing a small rounded rectangle, I am using RoundRect instead.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
  Dim hDC As IntPtr = e.Graphics.GetHdc
  Dim rc As New Rectangle(10, 10, 64, 24)
  Dim hPen As IntPtr = Win32.CreatePen(Win32.PenStyle.PS_SOLID, 0, _
                                       ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Green))
  Dim hOldPen As IntPtr = Win32.SelectObject(hDC, hPen)
  Call Win32.RoundRect(hDC, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Right, rc.Bottom, 10, 10)
  Win32.SelectObject(hDC, hOldPen)
  Win32.DeleteObject(hPen)
  e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC)
  MyBase.OnPaint(e)    
End Sub
```

This will draw a nice rounded rectangle, but it will also fill it with a white brush, erasing what I don't want to have erased.

How can I draw this without erasing the inside of the rectangle?

Comment: Why are you using pinvoke, and GDI+ API... why not just use the methods provided by the .net Graphic object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to select a stock, hollow brush before you draw the rectangle. Call GetStockObject with HOLLOW_BRUSH and then select that into the device context in the same way as you selected the pen.

Answer (score 1):

I use a method like this. Works fine for me.

```
private static GraphicsPath CreateRoundRectranglePath(Rectangle rect, Size rounding)
{
    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    var l = rect.Left;
    var t = rect.Top;
    var w = rect.Width;
    var h = rect.Height;
    var rx = rounding.Width;
    var dx = rounding.Width << 1;
    var ry = rounding.Height;
    var dy = rounding.Height << 1;
    path.AddArc(l, t, dx, dy, 180, 90); // topleft
    path.AddLine(l + rx, t, l + w - rx, t); // top
    path.AddArc(l + w - dx, t, dx, dy, 270, 90); // topright
    path.AddLine(l + w, t + ry, l + w, t + h - ry); // right
    path.AddArc(l + w - dx, t + h - dy, dx, dy, 0, 90); // bottomright
    path.AddLine(l + w - rx, t + h, l + rx, t + h); // bottom
    path.AddArc(l, t + h - dy, dx, dy, 90, 90); // bottomleft
    path.AddLine(l, t + h - ry, l, t + ry); // left
    path.CloseFigure();
    return path;
}
```